# Где заключается алгоритмическая ошибка кода в 1С?

Tags: функции, битрикс, 1с

`Прилагаю код для теста.

```
функция ВычислитьЦенуТовара (СуммаВключаетНДС, Кол_во, СуммаСНДС, СуммаНДС) 
    Если СуммаВключаетНДС Тогда
    Попытка
        Кол_во = Число(Кол_во);
    Исключение
    КонецПопытки;
    
    Попытка
        Сумма = Число(СуммаСНДС);
    Исключение
    КонецПопытки;
    
    Попытка
        СуммаНДС = Число(СуммаНДС);
    Исключение
    КонецПопытки;
    
    Возврат (СуммаСНДС-СуммаНДС)/Кол_во;
Иначе
    Возврат СуммаСНДС/Кол_во;
КонецЕсли;
Возврат 0;
 Конецфункции
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Функция по расчету цены товара. Где то допущена алгоритмическая ошибка кода.

Answer (score 1):

Я вообще не знаю 1С, но могу предположить по логике работы программы, что вместо `Сумма = Число(СуммаСНДС);` должно быть `СуммаСНДС = Число(СуммаСНДС);`. В противном случае может быть передано строковое значение, например, и функция не отработает.

P.S.: Просьба прикладывать код вместо фотографий

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, обязательно попробую!

Comment: @Salenblok, к тому же, если попытки не пройдут, а будут исключения, то в блоке `Возврат (СуммаСНДС-СуммаНДС)/Кол_во;` возможно будут значения переменных типа "Неопределено". Но тут надо уже контекст смотреть и типы.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего должно быть так:

```
функция ВычислитьЦенуТовара (СуммаВключаетНДС, Кол_во, СуммаСНДС, СуммаНДС) 

// преобразование выносим перед условием проверки наличия НДС, так-как получается что для С НДС мы приводим типы, а без - нет.
Попытка
    Кол_во = Число(Кол_во);
Исключение
    // нет обработки исключения, вероятно должно быть что то типа такого
    // Сообщить("Ошибка не удалось преобразовать кол-во в число!")
    // Возврат 0;
КонецПопытки;

Попытка
    СуммаСНДС = Число(СуммаСНДС);// Неверное имя переменной, должно быть СуммаСНДС, а не Сумма
Исключение
    // нет обработки исключения, вероятно должно быть что то типа такого
    // Сообщить("Ошибка не удалось преобразовать Сумму с НДС в число!")
    // Возврат 0;
КонецПопытки;

Попытка
    СуммаНДС = Число(СуммаНДС);
Исключение
    // нет обработки исключения, вероятно должно быть что то типа такого
    // Сообщить("Ошибка не удалось преобразовать Сумму НДС в число!")
    // Возврат 0;
КонецПопытки;

Если СуммаВключаетНДС Тогда
    Возврат (СуммаСНДС-СуммаНДС)/Кол_во;  
Иначе
    Возврат СуммаСНДС/Кол_во;
КонецЕсли;

Возврат 0;
```

Конецфункции

Comment: Еще неплохо было бы отслеживать деление на ноль